# C# richBox1 text disable

Tags: c#

I have problem with richBox1 text disabling.

I've tryed `richTextBox1.readonly = true;` and `richTextBox1.Enabled = false;`

My code:

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.ReadOnly = !richTextBox1.ReadOnly;
        }
```

Its disabling after one letter.

EDIT: And if disable I can still copy text but cant write there.

Comment: do you want to reject people copying your text ?

Comment: I mean if I ping with program and Ping info coming into richTextBox.
And I dont want someone can write into richTextBox but they can copy text there.

Comment: Disable it from the form load event..

Comment: What you mean "tye"?

Comment: And.... your code is already do what you want. ReadOnly true and Enable false. Select copy active, write disabled. No need for "richTextBox1_TextChanged"

Comment: The* double click on the form to activate the form loaded event, then add your code there.

Comment: Its disabling full box if i click and trying to select then it moves...

Comment: Thank you guys! Got work now

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, disabling expected functionality is not something you should be doing. It is not good UI design.

Answer (score 0):

The event `TextChanged` is fired every time the text changes (including writing or removing one letter). You can use Form's Load event (by double clicking the form on design time) :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   richTextBox1.ReadOnly = true;
   richTextBox1.Enabled = false;
}
```